# Merge data from two values of a tuple in Spark, Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a file with the following data:

> 1231212 name1 name2
>
> 1431344 name1 name3
>
> 2342343 name3 name4
>
> 2344255 name2 name1

and I would like my program in Java to perform some operations in Spark so that my output is the following:

> [(name1, 3), (name2, 2), (name3, 2), (name4, 1)]

but I am still not sure how to use flat and reduce operations. I just started learning Spark.

What I have right now is the following:

```
    List<Tuple2<String,Long>> result1 = 
            accessLogs.map(log -> new Tuple2<Long, String>(log.getTimestamp(), log.getHostname1()))
            .filter(tuple -> tuple._1() > init_time - 5)
            .filter(tuple -> tuple._1() < fin_time + 5)
            .map(e -> (new Tuple2<String, Long>(e._2, 1L)))
            .take(100);
    List<Tuple2<String, Long>> result2 = 
            accessLogs.map(log -> new Tuple2<Long, String>(log.getTimestamp(), log.getHostname2()))
            .filter(tuple -> tuple._1() > init_time - 5)
            .filter(tuple -> tuple._1() < fin_time + 5)
            .map(e -> (new Tuple2<String, Long>(e._2, 1L))) 
            .take(100);
```

so my results are two different lists with the following data:

> [(name1,1), (name1,1), (name3,1), (name2,1)]
>
> [(name2,1), (name3,1), (name4,1), (name1,1)]

What can I use to achieve the wanted result by using just one list?

My idea is to start like this:

```
 List<String> finalResult =
            accessLogs.map(log -> new Tuple3<Long, String, String>(log.getTimestamp(), log.getHostname1(), log.getHostname2()))
            .filter(tuple -> tuple._1() > init_time - 5)
            .filter(tuple -> tuple._1() < fin_time + 5)...
```

and then continue performing the operations.

Edit:

Now I have the following code:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs1 = accessLogs.mapToPair(new PairFunction<LogObject, String, Integer>() {
          public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(LogObject s) { return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s.getHostname1(), 1); }
        }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
              public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) { return a + b; }
        });
```

which returns

> [(name1,2), (name3,1), (name2,1)]

but I'm still missing the part about how to perform this (from the suggested answer)

> .flatMap{case(_, key1, key2) => List((key1, 1), (key2, 1))}

in Java so that I can retrieve the data from both the second and the third column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, but one way would be to use `flatMap` followed by `reduceByKey`. My Java-skills are a little rusty, so I will list it in Scala instead - hopefully you get the point and can then convert it yourself to Java :)

```
val result = accessLogs.flatMap{case(_, key1, key2) => List((key1, 1), (key2, 1))}.reduceByKey(_+_)
```

Comment: It's sadly much longer in Java, but I was able to do it using the flatMap and then reduceByKey. Thanks!